# Start new instance of a project using a button in form

Tags: envdte

I have a solution that contains 32 projects, one of which is a Windows form and the others are console applications. In the Windows form I have a combo box that its items are the names of the console application projects with a button. 
Now, my problem is that how can I start the console application, which name is selected in the combo box by pushing the button, in a new instance? (if it is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button click event, add the following lines, assuming cmbConsoleApps contains the file names of the console applications.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmbConsoleApps.Text);
```

More information about executing applications:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx